# Declare and compare a variable with Khmer unicode string in VBA, excel

Tags: vba, excel, unicode

Khmer unicode character string is different from other unicode character, we can't write it on VBA editor of Excel or MS Access.

How to declare a variable and assign Khmer unicode string?

Comment: Both question and answer with in 10 seconds. Thanks for info buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course refer to the answer in [declaring a unicode string in vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269399/declaring-a-unicode-string-in-vba-in-excel) help us to answer to Khmer unicode issue in Excel VBA as well.

I used tool: http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ to translate Khmer unicode string to hexa and then I added to each hexadecimal to use in VBA by &H.

Example of writing: ល.រ into VBA variable:

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr = ChrW(&H179B) & "." & ChrW(&H179A)
```

More detail in post: http://ask.osify.com/qa/231

Comment: What is this? You just asked a question dear.. just wait for an answer

Comment: People asked me and I solved it myself later so I just share it for other people to aware