# Adding a Hebrew Autocorrect entry using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I can add an English Autocorrect entry using VBA in Excel

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement What:="helo", Replacement:="hello"
```

However if the replacement word is Hebrew then it doesn't work (nothing is added)

```
aHebrewWord = Range("C1").Value
Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement What:="helo", Replacement:=aHebrewWord
```

I know that VBA does work with Hebrew, even though you can't actually see Hebrew in VBA (source [declaring a unicode string in vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269399/declaring-a-unicode-string-in-vba-in-excel)) - for instance the following function works fine:

```
function getReverse(aHebrewWord)
  getReverse=StrReverse(aHebrewWord)
end function
```

How can I add a Hebrew Autocorrect entry using VBA?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything preventing VBA from using one string instead of another. Are you sure the issue is with the string being Hebrew? How do you define `aHebrewWord`?

Comment: I think you are right... I think perhaps the problem is that I should have done ActiveSheet.Range("C1").value

Comment: Hi Avish. If you write a version of your comment as an answer I will accept it hopefully.

Comment: Done, although I'm not sure "your problem lies elsewhere" is a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be anything preventing VBA from using one string instead of another; your code should work.

The problem, if it exists, might be with the way you're obtaining `aHebrewWord`.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA editor expects VBA files to be encoded in `Windows-1252`, which is a 8-bit codepage and does not support hebrew.

You can either build your string as a concatenation of wide character code :

```
'this replace 'hello' to 'שלום'
Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement What:="hello", Replacement:=ChrW(&H05E9) & ChrW(&H05DC) & ChrW(&H05D5) & ChrW(&H05DD)
```

Or you can convert a `Windows-1252` string which is a binary equivalent of the unicode string:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.AddReplacement What:="hello", Replacement:=StrConv("éÜÕÝ", vbFromUnicode)
```

Use notepad to convert the string: copy-paste the unicode string, save the file as unicode (not utf-8) and open it as ASCII (which is in fact Windows-1252),then copy-paste it into the VBA editor without the first two characters (ÿþ), which is the BOM marker.

Comment: Thank you for your hard work writing a very specific answer.  I am sure that this will work. But I think the answer is as @Avish said, and as I wrote in my comment above, that I was just passing in the wrong parameter to the autocorrect function.