# VBA: Use of Public Property Get in place of Const (for Non-Unicode Characters)

Tags: vba, properties, constants

I have a VBA code where I need to define a constant string containing Non-Unicode characters (£). As some might know, VBA Editor doesn't support non-unicode and uses windows "System Locale" setting in regional and language setting to parse/map these characters. The machine I develop the code is set to English system Locale but some of the users have that setting as other languages, e.g. Chinese which turns the string constant to question mark (£ --> ?).

Now, £ = chr(163), however, you cannot use chr as part of defining a constant in VBA. So while this is **allowed**:

```
public const mystring = "reference constant string with £"
```

this is **not allowed** in VBA"

```
public const mystring = "reference constant string with " & chr(163).
```

One way around is to define mystring as a public/global variable:

> Constants.bas

```
public mystring as string
```

and then set the public variable on start of running code or Excel opening.

> ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    mystring = "reference constant string with " & chr(163).
End Sub
```

One issue with this process is the public variables get cleared when error happens or the code stops. To keep the value an alternate I came across was to avoid public variable and instead use a public property get. Note that I have to include this a part of a class.

> **.cls

```
Public Property Get mystring () As String
    mystring = "\R;;" & Chr(163)
End Property
```

So, now I am wondering if there will be any issue with this approach? or perhaps there is a better approach to address the constant variable with non-unicode character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678033/unicode-string-literals-in-vba

Comment: Thanks @sam! I hadn't came across this one! Useful info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is the name of the module, `Constants` - it's misleading, since neither a public/global *variable* nor a public get-only *property* are *constants*.

Side node, constants not being assignable to non-constant expressions isn't a limitation that's specific to VBA.

Properties are perfectly legal in standard modules, and public get-only properties are a perfectly fine way to expose a read-only value that needs to be constructed at run-time.

> *the public variables get cleared when error happens or the code stops*

Assuming "when error happens" involves clicking <kbd>End</kbd> and effectively ending the execution context, that is true of *everything* exposed anywhere, whether it's a global variable, a public property, an object, or anything that exists in-memory at run-time... and that's just normal stuff - the value is simply available on-demand any time.

Again there's no need to have a class module for this, this is perfectly legal in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get MyString() As String
    MyString = "\R;;" & Chr(163)
End Property
```

If re-creating the string every time the property getter is accessed is a problem, then you need a way to persist its value in a backing field - but then, this backing field (whether it's in a class or standard module) only has a value when the execution context exists, meaning it has exactly the same problem a global variable would have: execution stops, it's gone.

One work-around could be to use a class with the `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True` (default is `False`).

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "Class1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Option Explicit

Private internalString As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    internalString = "\R;;" & Chr(163)
End Sub

Public Property Get MyString() As String
    MyString = internalString
End Property
```

And now VBA will automatically create an instance of `Class1` whenever it's referenced, *as soon as it's referenced*, and that instance remains "alive" until an `End` statement is explicitly executed, or the execution context is otherwise terminated. Exactly like, say, a `UserForm` class, you access this *default instance* using the class name as an identifier:

```
Debug.Print Class1.MyString
```

If the default instance existed when `Class1` was referenced, the `internalString` is returned. If it didn't, then `Class_Initialize` executes, then the `internalString` is returned.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu Guindon, I tried the in-module property declaration and experiencing a little bit of strange behavior. It sometimes give me out of memory or automation error or crashes excel. The project I am working on is a bit code-heavy. Also I am only using this string at a few places. Have you had any experience with the memory usage of the property declaration outside the class ? I am trying to minimize the memory load with the change to this string.

Comment: What kind of string are we talking about? `"\R;;" & Chr(163)` is definitely not the cause of any memory issues...

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit surprised to see the issues for one simple string, could be something temporary. I am gonna try some more after a few clean excel restart to see if it happens again.