# font size does not change for non English language in vba

Tags: vba, hebrew

I am trying to use vba in order to collect text from excel and put it in a word document.

using the following script, I get the the style to affect only the English letters but the letters in Hebrew does not follow.

```vb
Sub WriteToWord()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim mydoc As Object

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.Activate

    Set mydoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

    With wordApp.Selection
        .Font.Size = 18
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TypeText ("a")
        .TypeText ("חדש")
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to copy the Hebrew string you have there in the end, but for me, it doesn't encode correctly, as it just shows `"???"` in the editor and in the Word document (notice that I'm on a Swedish computer, so it might still show the correct characters for you=.

It seems that the VBA editor only supports the Windows-1252 encoding (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23678551/4663244), so I'm curious about how you work with these characters :)

Here is a related question about how to use Unicode characters in a VBA script: [declaring a unicode string in vba in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269399/declaring-a-unicode-string-in-vba-in-excel)

Anyway, I got it to work if I used the function `ChrW` to write unicode characters (btw, I don't know for sure I used the correct characters, so please check that):

```vb
Sub WriteToWord()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim mydoc As Object

    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.Activate

    Set mydoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

    With wordApp.Selection
        .Font.Size = 18
        .Font.Bold = True
        .TypeText ("a")
        .TypeText (ChrW(1495) + ChrW(1491) + ChrW(1513))
    End With
End Sub
```